# Scraping all href links using Pagination

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've to Select each state from https://www.maxpreps.com/search/states_by_sport.aspx?gendersport=boys,football&season=fall and then click on team rankings and after that I've to grab href links of each ranked team.

I've completed till team rankings part now I want get links of each ranked team from all the pages in the pagination bar right now I'm getting links of all teams available on the first page only, I don't how to navigate to the next page.(below is  the code)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

site = "https://www.maxpreps.com"

url = requests.get("https://www.maxpreps.com/search/states_by_sport.aspx?gendersport=boys,football&season=fall")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
states = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'states'})
for each_state in states:
    all_states = each_state.find_all('a', href=True)
for a in all_states:
    domain = site + a['href']     #domain consist oflinks of states
    for r in domain:
        page_link = domain
        page_response = requests.get(page_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("rankings")}):
            rankings_link = site + link.get('href')
    #print(rankings_link)

    for ert in rankings_link:
        team_link = rankings_link
        page_response1 = requests.get(team_link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_response1.content, "html.parser")

        My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'mx-grid sortable rankings-grid'})
        links = My_table.findAll('a')
    print(links)
```

output:

```
<a href="/high-schools/everett-crimson-tide-(everett,ma)/football/home.htm">Everett</a>, <a href="/high-schools/methuen-rangers-(methuen,ma)/football/home.htm">Methuen</a>,
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just iterate through pages within the query parameters.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "https://www.maxpreps.com"

session = requests.Session()
response = session.get("https://www.maxpreps.com/search/states_by_sport.aspx?gendersport=boys,football&season=fall") 
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser") 
all_states = soup.find('div', {'class': 'states'}) 

states_list = []
for each in all_states.find_all('a'):
    states_list.append(each['href'].split('=')[-1])
states_list = states_list[:-1]    


team_links = []
url = 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/rankings/list.aspx'
for state in states_list:
    break_loop = False
    page=1
    while break_loop == False:
        print ('%s: Page %s' %(state, page))
        payload = {
                'page': str(page),
                'ssid': '8d610ab9-220b-465b-9cf0-9f417bce6c65',
                'state': state
                }

        response = requests.get(url, params=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser") 
        table = soup.find('table')
        if table == None:
            break_loop = True

        else:
            page+=1
            links = table.find_all('a')
            for link in links:
                team_links.append('https://www.maxpreps.com' + link['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (team_links[:10])
['https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/central-red-devils-(phenix-city,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/thompson-warriors-(alabaster,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/hoover-buccaneers-(hoover,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/oxford-yellow-jackets-(oxford,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/mountain-brook-spartans-(birmingham,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/hewitt-trussville-huskies-(trussville,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/mcgill-toolen-yellowjackets-(mobile,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/lee-generals-(montgomery,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/pinson-valley-indians-(pinson,al)/football/default.htm', 'https://www.maxpreps.com/m/high-schools/vestavia-hills-rebels-(vestavia-hills,al)/football/default.htm']
```

Comment: it's giving this as output return self.attrs[key]   KeyError: 'href'